# Celery worker disappeared without errors

Tags: python, redis, celery

I setup Celery with Django app and broker "Redis"

```
@task
def proc(product_id,url,did,did_name):
    ## some long operation here

@task
def Scraping(product_id,num=None):
    if num:
        num=int(num) ## this for i can set what count of subtasks run now
    res=group([proc.s(product_id,url,did,dis[did]) for did in  dis.keys()[:num]])()
    result = res.get()
    return sum(result)
```

First few subtasks run successful, but later any worker dissapears and new tasks are still in RECEIVED status. Because the worker which must operate it does not exist.

I setup minimal concurency and 2 workers in /etc/default/celeryd.

I monitor CPU and memory usage, no highload detected.

There are no errors in the Celery logs!!!

What's wrong?

```
[2015-12-19 04:00:30,131: INFO/MainProcess] Task remains.tasks.proc[fd0ec29c-436f-4f60-a1b6-3785342ac173] succeeded in 20.045763085s: 6
[2015-12-19 04:17:28,895: INFO/MainProcess] missed heartbeat from w2@server.domain.com
[2015-12-19 04:17:28,897: DEBUG/MainProcess] w2@server.domain.com joined the party
[2015-12-19 05:11:44,057: INFO/MainProcess] missed heartbeat from w2@server.domain.com
[2015-12-19 05:11:44,058: DEBUG/MainProcess] w2@server.domain.com joined the party
```

---

SOLUTION>>> --------------------------------------------------------------)))))

1. if you use django-celery and want use celery as daemon: **no use** app() http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html  , instead  you must setup your celery in /etc/default/celeryd direct to manage.py of your project as: CELERYD_MULTI="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"
2. do not disable heartbeats!!!!!

for use celery with direct to manage.py need:

1. create arg. CELERY_APP=""  in /etc/default/celeryd beacuse if you don't do it, beat will be make run-command with old argument "app".
2. add line: "export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="your_app.settings"" to celeryd config if you not use default settings

Comment: what do you mean by disappear?

Comment: i found this ^^^ lines in log

Comment: It could be a network problem, or it could be that your Redis is not accepting connections from your workers. Are the workers process alive? I mean do you see them in your process list machine?

Comment: workers allways restarted, but not accept tasks  after